# How to provide values for only certain views inside a cell while leaving some nil and not crash?

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, swift3

I have a coursework with some confusing specifications. I need to write an app to store details about the food that the user consumes. I have done all of it, I store the entries in a Core Data entities and I display them inside a table. The problem is that out of the 6 different pieces of information that the user can provide only 3 are mandatory (the name of the meal, the date and time and the food group). the other 3 (photo, meal type , and user id) he can skip. All my attributes inside core data are optional. It works just fine when I complete all the fields. As soon as I set the unnecessary 3 as nil I get a fatal error (found nil while unwrapping optional). Could someone please help with this one? Thank you. Code listing below.

```
 @IBAction func saveUserInput(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let userMeals = UserMeals(context: managedObjectContext!)
    if (mealName.text?.isEmpty)! || (foodGroup.text?.isEmpty)! || (dateAndTimeOfMeal.text?.isEmpty)!{
        let screenAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Warning!", message: "You must enter at least the name of the meal, the date and time, and the group!", preferredStyle: .alert)
        screenAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Got it!", style: .default, handler: nil))
        self.present(screenAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else if photoView?.image == nil || (mealType.text?.isEmpty)! || (userName.text?.isEmpty)!{
        userMeals.mealPhoto = nil
        userMeals.mealType = nil
        userMeals.userID = nil
        let screenNotification = UIAlertController(title: "Done!", message: "Your meal has been saved without a photo, meal type and user name!", preferredStyle: .alert)
        screenNotification.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Got it!", style: .default, handler: nil))
        self.present(screenNotification, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        userMeals.mealPhoto = NSData(data: UIImageJPEGRepresentation((photoView?.image)!, 0.5)!)
        userMeals.mealName = mealName?.text
        userMeals.foodGroup = foodGroup?.text
        userMeals.dateAndTime = dateAndTimeOfMeal?.text
        userMeals.mealType = mealType?.text
        userMeals.userID = userName?.text
        let screenNotification = UIAlertController(title: "Done!", message: "Your meal has been saved!", preferredStyle: .alert)
        screenNotification.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Got it!", style: .default, handler: nil))
        self.present(screenNotification, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Code from the table view class:

```
private func loadData() {
    let mealRequest: NSFetchRequest<UserMeals> = UserMeals.fetchRequest() // get all information from core, of type guardian.
    do {
        storedMeals = try managedObjectContext.fetch(mealRequest)
    } catch {
        print("could not load data from core \(error.localizedDescription)") // get more details from the error.
    }
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return storedMeals.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellForMeal", for: indexPath) as! ViewMealsCell
    let mealItem = storedMeals[indexPath.row]
    if let mealImage = UIImage(data: mealItem.mealPhoto as! Data) {
        cell.mealPhoto.image = mealImage
    }
    cell.mealName.text = mealItem.mealName
    cell.foodGroup.text = mealItem.foodGroup
    cell.dateAndTime.text = mealItem.dateAndTime
    cell.mealType.text = mealItem.mealType
    cell.userName.text = mealItem.userID
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete { // delete the row from the data source
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

The definition of user meals:

```
extension UserMeals {

@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<UserMeals> {
    return NSFetchRequest<UserMeals>(entityName: "UserMeals");
}

@NSManaged public var dateAndTime: String?
@NSManaged public var foodGroup: String?
@NSManaged public var mealName: String?
@NSManaged public var mealPhoto: NSData?
@NSManaged public var mealType: String?
@NSManaged public var userID: String?
```

}
[image: this is the error i get]

[image: how do i not do what it suggest me to do]

Comment: I edited the code listing with the UserMeals definition

Comment: I have added a photo with the crash details

Comment: I have done the if let before I asked the question....the result is the same...

Comment: will do right now..thank you for your time

Comment: i get a loop in the debugger. I put points in all the 3 data source functions. when i press step into or continue program execution it loops in number of sections and number of rows in section but doesn't go into cell for row at index path. it just shows me the page with the hex values. give me a sec please to redo the debug

Comment: if let mealImage = UIImage(data: mealItem.mealPhoto as! Data) {
            cell.mealPhoto.image = mealImage//
        }

Comment: this are the lines that throw the error. specifically cell.mealPhoto.image = mealImage

Comment: let me test it because it forces me to unwrap anyway. 2 secs pls

Comment: nope. the same throw at this line  if let mealImage = UIImage(data: (mealItem.mealPhoto as? Data)!) {

Comment: ok. I tried to do it. It forces me to !.. that line you see there is the solution provided by Xcode for the error. I understand perfectly why you saying that but Im not allowed. let me add a photo so you can convince your self.

Comment: i have added the photo with the error and the suggestion is the line that does the error because there is still forced unwrapping. Ok thank you for you time. I will look at your answer and try to do it.

Comment: ok. thank you for it. i will do it in a bit a ok it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
if let mealImage = UIImage(data: mealItem.mealPhoto as! Data) {
    cell.mealPhoto.image = mealImage
}
```

Any time you have an exclamation mark, you are saying "crash me, please." You cannot complain if the runtime does exactly what you asked it to do.

You want to use `as?` here. This will unwrap *safely*.

There may be additional safe unwrapping to do, but this, in general, is the approach you want to take. For example, you might write something like this:

```
if let data = mailItem.mealPhoto as? Data {
    cell.mealPhoto.image = UIImage(data:data)
}
```

In this way we first safe-unwrap `mealPhoto` into a Data and then safely create the image from that Data. You need to do it in two steps like this because you cannot call `UIImage(data:)` with a `Data?` parameter; you have to unwrap to a `Data` first.

---

**EDIT** As rightly pointed out in the comments, we need to set the `image` for *every* row, not just those for which we have data. So expand the above to the following:

```
if let data = mailItem.mealPhoto as? Data {
    cell.mealPhoto.image = UIImage(data:data)
} else {
    cell.mealPhoto.image = nil
}
```

In this way, we remove the image for reused table rows for which we have no image data.

Comment: but also - use this check as an opportunity to provide a default image for when you don't return valid data - otherwise you're going to end up displaying the mealPhoto from the last time the reusable cell was displayed 
if let data = mailItem.mealPhoto as? Data {
    cell.mealPhoto.image = UIImage(data:data)
} else {
    cell.mealPhoto.image = mealPhotoDefaultImage
}

Comment: @Russell Very good point. I'll add `nil` as an alternative. — When I wrote my answer, I was concentrating on the crash and the unwrapping, not on the fact that this is a table. :)